# Foldermill passing variables to a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, parameters

I am using a program called Foldermill.

Foldermill identifies when a PDF is saved into a folder.

I have setup a rule so that when a PDF is saved into a folder, a .bat file is executed.

[image]

The .bat file should receive the filepath and filename from Foldermill:

[image]

However, no parameters are being received by the .bat file:

[image]

Is anyone able to help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Your shown code will actually run the function twice. When `call` returns, (after `pause`), the next command run would be `echo param1: %~1`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of subroutines as smaller scripts that have been embedded in your main script. They get their own set of parameters, so the `%1` and `%2` that you have there are actually the parameters that were passed when you ran `call :function`. Since your code didn't forward along any of the parameters, your subroutine doesn't know that they exist.

To get around this, you can forward all of the arguments that were passed to the main script using `%*`.

```
call :function %*
```